What is the reason for using &*beg instead of beg when beg is an iterator?
In the book "A Tour of C++" (third edition for C++20) from Bjarne Stroustrup, section 18.5.2 packaged task, we have this piece of code :
// compute the sum of [beg:end) starting with the initial value init 
double accum(vector<double>::iterator beg, vector<double>::iterator end, double init)
{
     return accumulate(&*beg, &*end, init);
}

Why did Stroustrup use &* of the iterator instead of the iterator itself here? Is there any advantage, or difference, to doing it this way?

Think about what std::vector<double>::iterator::operator* actually does/returns.  There's probably a dupe for this.

is it a mistake?  No, it is very intentional.  It's a learning point.  And it doesn't work for other container types that do not store their elements contiguously.

you will obtain a reference to double but accumulate takes an iterator as parameter

you will obtain a reference to double  Not quite right.  You'll object a double*, which is itself (in this case) a valid iterator.

So why prefer a double* to a std::vector::iterator ?

I do hope he says later on that &*end is Undefined Behaviour (assuming end is obtained from end() method).

This is a good question. I don't see the advantage here either. I'd reread the section around where this is done to see if he explains his reasoning a few pages earlier or later.

@Yksisarvinen not at all !

Side note: No stl used here. stl refers to the Standard Template Library, a hugely influential library from the 1990s that provided a huge amount of inspiration, and in many cases early implementations of the C++ Standard Library. Even 25 years later you can often see echoes in the naming of implementation details.

@kingsjester Even iterators over contiguous memory are sometimes wrapped in some fancy stuff (so, not always a raw pointer), for debugging purposes etc. By dereferencing the iterator and taking the address of the object, you get a raw pointer - and presumably faster iteration. I don't see why that is in a book though...

So why prefer a double* to a std::vector<double>::iterator?  I think it was just for the concurrency example of splitting up a vector for accumulation into separate parts.  I'm reading 18.5.2 now, I'm disappointed that the &*end gaffe wasn't called out.  It's a mistake, and corrected in the errata.

@Eljay thanks, post it as answer and I will accept it

@Eljay "we shouldn't pass pairs of pointer when we can use a span instead" doesn't really say that it was a mistake in the first place though.

@TedLyngmo • True, not called out explicitly.  Dodged the mistake by getting rid of the offending code, and doing it a little different, and showcasing span.  I'll let someone else provide a better answer.  (I've already bothered Bjarne enough this year.)

Duplicate addresses a potential problem with the code but does not address why Stroustrup chose to use this particular trick here.

@user4581301 That is technically true. Given the errata, it's likely a mistake in the first place so I'm not sure it's very useful to have a separate question for that (especially one that could likely be only answered by Stroustrup if they haven't already documented it somewhere). Alternatively, the duplicate target could be edited to add the "why did stroustrup do this", and then answers addressing that could be added there. If neither of the above is a good solution, I don't have strong feelings about using that dupe target.

@cigien Neither do I or I would have removed it rather than just commenting, but Eljay notes in a comment above that this bit of code is corrected in the errata. That pretty much make the answer, "Oooops."

There was a time before the concept of Contiguous Iterators where raw pointers could be used by a function that required a contiguous range.

As indicated by Eljay in comment, the fact that B.Stroustrup use a double* here instead of a std::vector<double>::iterator in this case seems a mistake, since he corrected that in the errata.
This syntax is undefined behavior as explained in this answer.
